# Is a merchant required to link his bank account on Balanced Payments?

Tags: balanced-payments

Does balanced payments require a merchant to have his bank account linked to the account to accept credits?  What is the bare amount of information required to create a "user"?  I want to have the least amount of friction possible until the merchant has incentive to input more information (when they're getting paid). Ideally, I would show the user screen to collect the last bit of information the first time they try to get cash out of my marketplace.

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's a vendor technical support question, and is off-topic here at StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information about what types of questions are (and are not) appropriate to ask here. Keeping things on-topic helps SO remain a useful programming reference. Thanks.

Comment: Balanced is trying to consolidate their questions on SO.  This seems to be borderline per the FAQ.

Comment: In what way is it borderline? There's no programming aspect to the question whatsoever, it's not a programming tool or library, and not an IDE. It's a vendor support question, and regardless of what "Balanced is trying to do" it doesn't make it on topic here. Sorry.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a vendor's policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Balanced nonclementure payments to people are called Credits and the user is represented by an Account.

For an Account to [accept an ACH payment](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/merchant) it must have the role "merchant". Since Balanced underwrites the merchant account you must provide identifying information before the role can be added.

In the best case scenario a merchant can be identified by using their name, DOB, and address. If Balanced cannot identify the user from this information alone then you, as the developer, will have the choice of either [prompting them for additional information](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/merchant#requests-for-more-information) and resubmitting the request or redirecting them to the Balanced website for information.

To satisfy your requirement you can keep the money in your marketplace escrow account until the payment is due and you have prompted them for the information to create their account. This will require some book-keeping on your end to keep track of the funds until they are disbursed.